# Printing a string of text into multiple lines? Java

Tags: java

I am using the scanner utility to read a sentence inputted from the keyboard. I want to know how to be able to transform this string text into multiple lines..

So for example, If I were to enter

```
"How are you  doing?" (two spaces between you and doing)
```

How would I be able to make this print onto multiple lines?

```
How
are
you

doing?
```

*SOLVED* by using System.out.println(str.replace(" ", "\n"))

Thanks all.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Take a look to String split method.

Comment: Are the numbers part of the desired output?

Comment: I've only been able to create the scanner and have it print out the input, but I cant figure out a simple solution to having the string print out on multiple lines.

Comment: If you change your requirements in the comments below some answers, you are effectively wasting our time trying to help you based on the information you provide in the question.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, first time i've used this site as I was becoming very frustrated trying to find a solution over the web. Will change my OP. Thanks for the help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

First take input using scanner. 
Then split the inputed line using input.split(" ") and store it into String array.
At last print the array using loop or Arrays.tostring() method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s ="How are you   doing?".replaceAll("  +","  ");
    String[] str = s.split(" ");
    System.out.println(str.length);
    for(String temp: str){
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}
```

Try this : It will print only one space if there are more than two spaces in a given String.

Try using only `System.out.println();`

```
System.out.println(string.replaceAll("  +", "  ").replace(" ", "\n"));
```

Comment: Is it possible to be able to just use a System.out.println statement or if statement?

Comment: @user2086204 You want to print one space if there are more than 2 spaces in the given input ...yes?

Comment: System.out.println(str.replace(" ", "\n")); this line made everything work. Although do you know how I would be able to make it print the number of non blank lines within my string?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        String lines = a.nextLine();
        boolean emptyLine = true;

        for (String line : lines.split(" ")) {
            if (!"".equals(line.trim())) {
                System.out.println(line);
                emptyLine = true;

            } else if (emptyLine) {
                System.out.println();
                emptyLine = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: There are 3 spaces between _you_ and _doing_ but only one empty line.

Comment: I have to use the input from the scanner rather than declaring text within the code.

Comment: Now It won't print the empty line that OP wants in his example.

Comment: I have added modified logic. Added scanner support and it will not print empty line.

Comment: @Real: I think OP wants one empty line. See his example.

Comment: @jlordo Added support you was looking for.

Comment: @Real: I am looking for nothing, OP is looking ;) My solution is one line of code ;) See my answer...

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the simple line of System.out.println(str.replace(" ", "\n")); does what i need to my output to look like.

Comment: Please stop searching for "Thanks & Regards" and editing it out. It is cluttering up the review queue and does not improve the posts very much. If you're going to edit them, edit more than just the "thanks" part out.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(" +", "\n"));
```

#### Edit:

The calculate the number of non blank chars:

```
int chars = str.replace(" ", "").length();
```

Comment: There are 3 spaces between _you_ and _doing_ but only one empty line.

Comment: This works, I mis-read my instructions and saw that I was only required two spaces instead of the three!

Comment: Is there a way to read the number of non-blank characters within the string and print that?

Comment: See edited answer for an update that handles multiple spaces, and also how to calculate the number on non blank chars